# How to get facebook uid in firebase using react?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am using react and firebase auth using facebook. I am using the following code to sign in using facebook.

```
  const result = await auth().signInWithPopup(provider)
```

The full code is

```
import React, {
Component
} from 'react'
import './StartPage.css'
import fire from '../../fire.js'
import {
provider,
auth
} from '../../fire.js';
class StartPage extends Component {


constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.login = this.login.bind(this)

    this.loggedIn = this.loggedIn.bind(this)
}
async login() {
    provider.addScope('user_birthday');
    const result = await auth().signInWithPopup(provider)
    console.log(result)
      console.log(result.credential.accessToken)
    this.setState({
        user: result.user
    });
   console.log("Logged in")
    this.props.history.push('/vote')
}


loggedIn() {
    console.log('meh')
    // make check for login here
    this.props.history.push('/vote')
}

render() {

    return ( <
        div className = "StartPage" >
        <
        div className = "StartPage-up" >
        <
        div className = "StartPage-up-logo-container" >
        <
        img className = "StartPage-up-logo"
        src = "http://koyilandykoottam.in/images/home/logo.png" / >
        <
        /div> <
        div className = "StartPage-up-poy" > PERSON OF THE YEAR < /div> < /
        div > <
        div className = "StartPage-down" >
        <
        button className = "StartPage-facebook-login"
        onClick = {
            this.login
        } >
        Login with facebook <
        /button> < /
        div > <
        /div>
    )
}
}

export default StartPage
```

Logging result.user shows me only displayName and email id of the logged in user. Is there a way to get the facebook uid of the person logged in?

Comment: Have you configured fb app properly and added required permissions?

Comment: Yes, i am getting the displayname and email id of the user. I need the uid of the person to check against an already existing database

Comment: Ok, show your code so I can help you better

Comment: Please check the edit

Answer (score 0):

You don't get the uid automatically. You will need to call on facebook's graph api to get that data. One way to do it is to fetch the data when you redirect after logging in, so...

```
componentDidMount() {
    auth.getRedirectResult().then(result => {
      if (result.credential) {
        var token = result.credential.accessToken;
        axios
          .get(`https://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token=${token}&fields=id,name`
          )
          .then(result => console.log({ myData: result.data.data }))
          .catch(error => console.log(error));
      }
    });

  }
```

- GraphAPI to try out different calls https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer
- Docs for all the things you can query on a user call https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

> firebase.auth().currentUser.providerData[0].uid

more info at: 
https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users